# Connecting to VMWare Workstation using VMWare VIX

Tags: c#, vmware, vix

I'm trying to connect to my local vmware Workstation using the VIX API (VixCOMWrapper.dll, Interop.VixCOM.dll).

When i'm trying the code below, I'm getting an exception saying:

> "Cannot connect with multiple service providers."

I also tried passing localhost in the server name and i'm getting the same exception, any ideas?

```
VIX.Host vix_host_local;
vix_host_local = VIX.VixCOMWrapper.Instance.Connect(VIX.Enums.VIX_SERVICEPROVIDER.VMWARE_WORKSTATION, "", 0, "", "");
```

Update: the problem happens because before I did the following:

```
VIX.VixCOMWrapper.Instance.Connect(VIX.Enums.VIX_SERVICEPROVIDER.VMWARE_VMWARE_VI_SERVER, "", 0, "", "");
```

Now apparently this dll won't let me use 2 modes, I tried disconect() I tried dispose() and even tried running these 2 modes on different AppDomain and dispose it, nothing worked,
Any ideas ?